# Tag wiki edits linking to Documentation

Tags: discussion, tags, documentation, tag-wiki, documentation-topics

It was brought to my attention by [this tag wiki edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13096587) that some users are submitting edits solely to add links to the corresponding Documentation topic from the tag.

This is, I think, superfluous given that tag search pages already include links to Documentation if a topic for that Stack Overflow tag exists. For example, from the [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) page in that edit:

[image: On the Android tag search page]

Am I correct in rejecting these edits?

Comment: That box should just be added to the tag wiki page too, which would make this edit obsolete and repetitive anyways.

Comment: @animuson it looks like this has been added to the tag wikis as a sidebar, great! But I still see a lot of suggested edits that do nothing more than add a link to the Documentation page. Perhaps it's a good idea to add a "don't add links to documentation"-warning when people try to edit this in (if possible)?